# Parsing JSON in PHP to extract values

Tags: php, json, parsing

I need to parse a JSON in my PHP code.

A simple sample ....

```
    $myJSON_string = '{
    "features": [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [7.671718, 44.912186]
            },
            "properties": {
                "ca": 183.5372,
                "key": "xyz"
            }
        }, {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [7.685436, 44.921234]
            },
            "properties": {
                "ca": 183.5372,
                "key": "kwh"
            }
        }

    ],
    "type": "FeatureCollection"
}';



    $myJSON_json = json_decode($myJSON_string,true);

    foreach ($myJSON_json as $f) {
        echo $f['features']['properties'][0]['key'].'<br />';
    }
```

I'd like to extract the values of "key" parameter, so in this sample

```
xyz
kwh
```

I'm quite a newbie in PHP, so sorry .... Any suggestions / example / alternative?

Thank you a lot in advance!

Cesare

Comment: Just do a `print_r($myJSON_json);` and you will see the structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate `features` array.

```
foreach ($myJSON_json['features'] as $f) {
    echo $f['properties']['key'].'<br />';
}
```